# Should I be able to type assert a slice of string maps?

Tags: go

I am receiving a message using the [Go NSQ library](http://github.com/bitly/go-nsq) where a field is a slice of `map[string]string`'s. I feel like I should be able to type assert this field as `value.([]map[string]string)` but it's failing and I can't tell if this is expected or not.

This snippet replicates the behavior https://play.golang.org/p/qcZM880Nal

Why does this type assertion fail?

Comment: Why would people downvote this question? It was a legitimate question and received a helpful answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered briefly [here in the FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface).

The types `[]interface{}` and `[]map[string]string` have two different representation in memory. There is no direct way to convert between them.

Also, even when a conversion is allowed, you should note that you can't successfully assert to a different basic type at all (http://play.golang.org/p/zMp1qebIZZ). You can only assert to the original type, or another type of interface,

```
// panics
var i interface{} = int32(42)
_ = i.(int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

The conversion referred to doesn't work as described in Jim's answer. However, if you actually have the type you claim, and the interface you state it implements is just `interface{}` then the type assertion works fine. I don't want to speculate on the details of why the other doesn't work but I believe it's because you would have to unbox it in two phases as the `map[string]string`'s inside the slice are actually being viewed as some `interface{}` themselves. Here's an example;

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var value interface{}

    value = []map[string]string{{"address": string("this is interface literal")}}
    // value = []map[string]string{{"address": "this is map literal"}}

    AssertIt(value)


}

func AssertIt(value interface{}) {
    if str, ok := value.([]map[string]string); ok && len(str) > 0 {
        fmt.Println(str[0]["address"])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nope")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hJfoh_havC

Comment: yes, that's why he commented out the obvious assertion that he knows works

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by reflect in 2022

```golang
res := `[
        {
         "name": "jhon",
         "age": 35
        },
         {
         "name": "wang",
         "age": 30
        }
     ]`
// res := `{
//  "name": "jhon",
//  "age": 35
// }`
var rst any
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(res), &rst)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
t := reflect.TypeOf(rst).Kind()
fmt.Println(t)
```